# uploading file chunk by chunk in php manually

Tags: php, upload

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a upload handler that can upload the file chunk by chunk manually (not automatic php file uploader)

Comment: Clarify your question. What's an automatic php file uploader? Are you trying to do this from your browser, or are you making the request from PHP?

Comment: Usually php automatically handles file uploading process. I need to override this procedure and make it manual so I can create my own upload http handler.

Comment: And it's completely a server side thing

Answer (score 1):

You need something at client side, something that would split your file into chunks, send over HTTP to the server, receive responses and handle them. This is usually achieved with Flash and Java, the latter of which is more preferred method, as Java has richer library that can handle files... [jumpLoader](http://www.jumploader.com) would be a good choice for this...

Answer (score 0):

For a pure PHP solution, you could read the file in chunks and send it back to the server using cURL.